# How to perform a minCheckBox validation on jQuery Validate Engine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

In a form with three checkboxes I need to validate at least one of them has been checked. The company I work for is using [jQuery Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine). I am testing with the latest version/release.

As per library requirements my code should looks like:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" value="1" id="agreement_0" class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" value="1" id="agreement_1" class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" value="1" id="agreement_2" class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox">
```

If I go that way indeed the validation does work and at least one of them is required however my `$_POST` only contains the last of them, I guess is because they are sharing the same name (which I think is incorrect). Here are the docs for [minCheckbox](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#mincheckboxinteger).

If I use instead the following approach (which is the correct as per my knowledge) then I end up with Javascript errors:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement[]" value="1" id="agreement_0" class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement[]" value="1" id="agreement_1" class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement[]" value="1" id="agreement_2" class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox">
```

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   input[name=agreement[]]

Bottom line:

- With the first approach validation does work properly but I am only getting the value of the last input once posting the form.
- With the second approach validation fails with a Javascript error but I should be getting all the inputs on the array `agreement[]`.

Am I missing something here? How would you do this validation using jQuery Validation Engine?

Note: I can provide more details if needed and I can't change the library at this point in time.

Comment: Can you just change the names to agreement1, 2, and 3?

Comment: checkboxes and radio buttons work the same in that if you select any with the same `name`, only that will be selected and therefore submitted.

Comment: @JasonPelletier tried that too but then since the names are different then I will need to check all of them and not only one. For some reason the library relies on the name attr and in order to do the count has to be the same. See [here](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/js/jquery.validationEngine.js#L1359-L1367)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me, am i missing something?

```js
$('form').validationEngine();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/jquery.validationEngine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/validationEngine.jquery.css"/>

My Form
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="agreement[]" value="1" id="agreement_0" class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox">A
  <input type="checkbox" name="agreement[]" value="1" id="agreement_1" class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox">B
  <input type="checkbox" name="agreement[]" value="1" id="agreement_2" class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox">C
</form>
```

Comment: I think he needs to know which one is checked and his $_post is only getting the last one

Comment: If you want to distinguish you need to set different `value` for each element. But this is just the html I copied from the question.

Comment: What @Pilan posted is exactly the same I have in here but for some "weird" reason is not working for me. That way I will have an array of values where the selected one should be traveling with the value or so (have to check that part)

Comment: Check versions, maybe there is the problem :)

Comment: Found it ... another plugin doing this `var allInputs = $('input[name=' + input.attr('name') + ']');` no quotes correct way should be `var allInputs = $('input[name="' + input.attr('name') + '"]');` (I almost lost my head finding this)